# Disabling the software escape button on touchbar

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, touch-bar

Is there any way to disable permanently the software Escape button on the Touch Bar. After two months I can't get used it, and can't help touching it inadvertently in the middle of some important operations.

Any solution other than drilling through the touchbar is welcome.

Comment: It's horrible – I keep hitting it after months of getting used...

Comment: See the full answer for this duplicate: BTT

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove it, it's permanent (unless viewing expanded touch bar view).